# Banding - Color Depth / Dithering Problem

Tags: 16.04, xorg, display, colors, color-depth

I see a lot of gradient banding in Ubuntu. When I boot into Windows and look at the same image, the problem is gone. I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, with Ubuntu Gnome Desktop with an Intel Ivybridge Mobile "graphics card". My display has native 8 bit color.

I tried `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --set dithering On`

Not working.

I also tried to create a xorg.conf file, but that also not seems to be working.

`xwininfo -root | grep Depth` says:

```
Depth: 24
```